# matlab error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'containers.Map'

Tags: matlab, dictionary

I am trying to write a script that counts the maximum number of consecutive rounds a genome is alive in a pool. I do this using the following code:

```
dd = dir('*.csv');

fileNames = {dd.name}; 

data = cell(numel(fileNames),2);
data(:,1) = regexprep(fileNames, '.csv','');

for i = 1:numel(fileNames)    
   data{i,2} = dlmread(fileNames{i});
end

cc = distinguishable_colors(numel(fileNames));                % get better colormap

livedlong = containers.Map;                                   % contains all the streaks

for k = 1:numel(fileNames)

    strat = data{k,1}(10:end); % get strategy name
    XY = data{k,2};            % get data
    X = XY(:,1);               % get rounds
    Y = XY(:,2);               % get #tiles
    streak = 1;                % set streak counter to 1
    longestStreak = streak;    % set longestStreak to 1        


    %%% Calculate the streaks!
    for l = 1:(numel(X)-1)
        if ((X(l)+1) == X(l+1))
            streak = streak + 1;
            if (streak > longestStreak)
                longestStreak = streak;
            end
        else
            streak = 1;
        end
    end

    livedlong(strat)=longestStreak;              % save the streaks

end

k = keys(livedlong);
v = values(livedlong);
for i = 1:length(livedlong)
    plot(k{i}, v{i}, 'o', 'color', cc(i,:))
end
```

However, the last 5 rows (or rather calling: `keys(livedlong)` or `values(livedlong)`) yields the following error: `Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'containers.Map'.` and I have no idea why. I was able to use the commands on the Map in the command window a while ago, but now I cannot do that either.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a functioning [MCVE] and the *actual* error message, not your paraphrasing of it. You've very likely either overloaded `keys` or `values` somewhere or `k` or `v` are not the data type you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You must have variables named `keys` and/or `values` in your workspace and MATLAB is trying to use your `container.Map` instance as an index (by calling `subsindex`) and failing.

Either remove those variables:

```
clear keys values
```

Or use the dot notation for invoking those methods

```
k = livedlong.keys();
v = livedlong.values();
```

This is another good reason to use a function rather than a script so the workspace of your current function isn't polluted by what was run beforehand.

Comment: It might have been the case that I once overwrote them, because restarting matlab solved the issue.